# Regex reformat of text string with GPS coordinates

Tags: regex, google-maps, gps

Trying to convert this list (over 100,000 lines) into formatted coordinates for a google heat map.

```
us,waynesboro,Waynesboro,GA,,33.0897222,-82.0158333
us,waynesville,Waynesville,GA,,31.2291667,-81.7894444
us,wayside,Wayside,GA,,33.0611111,-83.6050000
us,weather wood,Weather Wood,GA,,33.6775000,-84.2980556
```

converted to:

```
new google.maps.LatLng(37.783383, -122.439594),
```

Comment: Over 100000 lines I think using RegEx may have some disadvantage in performance.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use

```
/\D.\D+/g
```

which selects the text I don't want and then replace it with the google syntax using:

```
),\rnew google.maps.LatLng(
```

http://www.regexr.com/38qlc